# spring /oauth/token, AuthorizationFailureEvent -> AuthenticationSuccessEvent

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot 2, OAuth2, and I use InMemoryTokenStore.

I have defined the following setting:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        ;
    }
...
}
```

To get a token I'm making the following request:

```
curl Standard:Login@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=passUser
```

Next, the following event chain occurs:

1) The first event raised is **AuthorizationFailureEvent**:

```
principal = anonymousUser
configAttributes = [fullyAuthenticated]
details = org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null
exceptionClass = AccessDeniedException
source = FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?username=user&password=passUser&grant_type=password
authorities = [ROLE_ANONYMOUS]
exceptionMessage = Access is denied
timestamp = 2017-12-01 14:45:34
```

2) Then **AuthenticationSuccessEvent**:

```
details = remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>
source = org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@eb5a2d91: Principal: {
 "id":" user",
 "password": "****",
 "authorities": ["USER"],
 "firstName": "",
 "lastName": "",
 "accountNonExpired": "true",
 "credentialsNonExpired": "true",
 "accountNonLocked": "true",
 "enabled": "true"
}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: "USER"
timestamp = 2017-12-01 14:45:36
```

3) And finally the server successfully returns a token:

```
{
  "access_token" : "2d37dd06-0f35-441f-a851-96d145836eed",
  "token_type" : "bearer",
  "expires_in" : 863999,
  "scope" : "all"
}
```

---

Please help me understand: 
What settings should I make so that event **AuthorizationFailureEvent** does not occur?

Comment: To get a token I'm making the following request: `curl Standard:Login@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=passUser` - client id=Standard, password=Login

Comment: Usually this `Standard:Login@localhost:8080` any server interprets as `client id=Standard, password=Login` for basic authentication

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/RYAX3VpoIIilHzywfF4fsg

Comment: see: https://youtu.be/FVifT2UIJoE

Comment: for tests i use Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3. And it makes 2 requests!!!! ))))) First one without Authorization!

Comment: @dir You were right from the beginning. Thank you for your help!

Comment: this client is from apache project https://hc.apache.org/  I've never used it before, and it's a big surprise that it doesn't work correctly in the box.